# How to read the variable Name which store the value

Tags: tcl, tclsh

TCL Program Sample:

```
proc fun { x } {
    puts "$$x = $x"
}
set a 10
fun $a
```

In this above program which prints the output as `$10 = 10` But i would like to get `a = 10` has the output. The variable which passes the values has to be read and the corresponding values as well. Is there a way to read the variable name.

Comment: `$` is to make de-reference the variable value, but you are giving the value in place of it. Unless you have another variable pointing to your actual variable, you can not de-reference the same. Remember, a variable name can be unique, but values are not. Multiple variables can have also have same value.

Answer (score 2):

```
proc fun name {
    upvar 1 $name var
    puts "$name = $var"
}
set a 10
fun a
```

The upvar command takes a name and creates an alias of a variable with that name.

Documentation:
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[upvar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a currently-supported version of Tcl (8.5 or 8.6), you can use `info frame -1` to find out some information about the caller. That has all sorts of information in it, but we can do a reasonable approximation like this:

```
proc fun { x } {
    set call [dict get [info frame -1] cmd]
    puts "[lindex $call 1] = $x"
}

set a 10
fun $a
# ==> $a = 10
fun $a$a
# ==> $a$a = 1010
```

Now, the use of `lindex` there is strictly wrong; it's Tcl code, not a list (and you'll see the difference if you use a complex command substitution). But if you're only ever using a fairly simple word, it works well enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
% set x a
a
% set a 10
10
% eval puts $x=$$x
a=10
% puts "$x = [subst $$x]"
a = 10
% puts "$x = [set $x]"
a = 10
%
```

If you are passing the variable to a procedure, then you should rely on `upvar`.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there is another way which I found on some other forum pages.

upvar is faster if accessing/using the var more than once, otherwise if only used once and it is a global var "[set ::[set name]]" could be better.

The proc below uses the global namespace to check it exists and sets a default value if not. The prints the current value.

```
proc setvardefault {name value} {
  # if global var name does not exist set it to value
  if {![info exists ::[set name] ]} { set ::[set name] $value }
  # print the current value of global var name
  puts "# INFOCHECK $name : [set ::[set name]]"
  #upvar 1 $name var
  #puts "# INFOCHECK $name : $var"
}
```

Only puts is needed for the printing part.